# When I run cypress as npm run cypress run build fails

Tags: gitlab-ci, cypress

I have installed cypress using npm as npm install cypress --save-dev .
I used the same command in .gitlab-ci.yml file 
When i run the command npm run cypress run locally , IDE opens and when i double click the spec.js file , then the tests run.
But I i use the same command on the gitlab pipeline , it says

> cypress open "run"
>   It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 4.1.0
>   [07:45:16]  Verifying Cypress can run /osmc/ux/framework-acceptance-tests/cache/Cypress/4.1.0/Cypress [started]
>   [07:45:18]  Verifying Cypress can run /osmc/ux/framework-acceptance-tests/cache/Cypress/4.1.0/Cypress [completed]
>   Opening Cypress...

and build fails .
Am i missing anything here ?

Comment: Can you highlight what is the command you are using? something like `npm run test`?

Comment: It looks like you are running `npx cypress run open` locally, but on ci you need to run `npx cypress run test`

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's opening the test runner, which is used locally via `npx cypress open`.

From that output it looks like you're running `npx cypress open run`, which isn't a real command and will open the runner

In CI you need to use `npx cypress run`, which will run tests without user interaction.  https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#How-to-run-commands

Answer (score 0):

Your gitlab.yml file should accomodate for the npm installations.
One example is as below. Meanwhile also please check the test/run command for your specs under package.json file. use the same command to trigger the test in pipeline.

---

```
stages:
 - test

test:
image: cypress/browsers:node12.14.1-chrome85
stage: test
script:
     npm i
     npm run start:ci &
     npx cypress run
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have your `.gitlab-ci.yml` with:

```yaml
stages:
  - test

cypress-test:
  image: cypress/browsers:node16.14.0-slim-chrome99-ff97
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npx cypress run
```